# Combine codes so that results can display in one table

Tags: sql

I wonder how to combine these two into one so that I can have one table displaying both number of "loves" and "hates" together

```
select count(id) as number
from review 
where text like "%love%" 
select count(id) as number
from review 
where text like "%hate%"
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Usually single quotes are used for strings, like `'%love%'`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
select sum(case when text like '%love%' then 1 else 0 end) as love_number,
       sum(case when text like '%hate%' then 1 else 0 end) as hate_number
from review 
where text like '%love%' or text like '%hate%'
```

(The WHERE clause isn't really needed, but will keep read-set size down etc.)

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, thank you for correcting the query. (Too fast copy-and-paste error... embarrasing)

Answer (score 0):

Use union all

```
select count(id) as number
from review 
where text like "%love%" 
union all
select count(id) as number
from review 
where text like "%hate%"
```

Comment: This gives you two rows, each with a number, and you wouldn't even know which number belongs to which text, because without an `ORDER BY` clause the rows come in arbitrary order.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The OP said "I wonder how to combine these two into one ".  I saw 2 queries, and I understood the OP wanted to combine those 2 queries into one. That's possible with `UNION ALL`. Where the OP asked for 1 record? I understand what you mean, but don't blame the answer but the question!

Comment: Two rows is okay, but as the result can be, say, 20 | 50 or 50 | 20 for the same data, where you wouldn't know which is the love count and which is the hate count, I consider this solution incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you want to achieve but perhaps the following SQL is good for you. It shows the count of the reviews:

```
select count(id) as number
from review 
where text like '%love%' or text like '%hate%';
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will fix the issue

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT ID FROM REVIEW WHERE text like %Love%) AS LOVE,
COUNT(SELECT ID FROM REVIEW WHERE text like %Hate%) AS HATE 
FROM REVIEW
```

Comment: No, you don't want a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (for which you are missing the `ON` clause anyway), but a `CROSS JOIN`. Then, you want to join queries. For this to happen you must put them into parentheses. At last you are lacking a main select clause. You want `select love.number as love_number, hate.number as hate_number from (select count(*) as number from review where text like '%love%') love cross join (select count(*) as number from review where text like '%hate%') hate;`.

Comment: I don't understand what you refer to with duplicates and where you want to apply `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Check it again now

Comment: That's a completely different answer. And the new query will fail with a runtime error. `COUNT(<expression>)` expects an expression that results in a single value, but you put a query there (missing additional parentheses around the queries and single quotes around the strings) that would return many values (IDs). You probably want `select (select count(*) from review where text like '%love%') as love, (select count(*) from review where text like '%hate%') as hate;`